# How do Elliot Alderson and Cisco communicate with dark army in Mr. Robot?

Tags: mr-robot

How do Elliot Alderson and Cisco communicate with dark army in Mr. Robot?

Is it IRC or some other mode of communication? I assume its not IRC because IRC is not at all secure, it's just plain text sharing.

Is this mode of communication secure and encrypted? In the series we can see a terminal on which they login to "some service" with a handle?

Answer (score 5):

Yes they use IRC. It's a common communication method for hackers and devious sorts. [IRL the hacking semi-group Anonymous uses/used it](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2011/05/the-hackers-hacked-main-anonymous-irc-servers-seized/). The TV show even set up a [augmented reality game using the IRC channel](http://heavy.com/entertainment/2016/07/mr-robot-how-to-access-elliot-irc-chat-ip-colo-solutions-net-the3g3ntl3man-make-work-hint-clue/) that Elliot uses in the show.

It doesn't need to be encrypted as they are talking in code and route through multiple servers to reach it. But IRC does support encrypted communication and administrative privileges and user control, so it could be secure.

Comment: Also important to add is the fact that modern IRC servers and clients support encryption "tacked on" similar to how HTTPS secured the older HTTP standard.